# WPF - How to get object bound to each ListItem using Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Please see the following code snippet first.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <mynamespace:MyCustomControl MyItem="{Binding MyObjectList/}" DefaultDistance="0.25" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part}" FontSize="16pt" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to display each and every item in MyObjectList using MyCustomControl. That item is a custom object with several properties. I was able to assign Text of a TextBlock to MyObject.Part, but unable to get the MyObject itself. I tried several Path options but did not succeed. Would you please help me on that? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to display a List of Objects in a particular way. Have you read about DataTemplates of ListViews and considered using this alternative.

If yes, please post the code of your MyCustomControl

Comment: The MyCustomControl is used in other project and it works fine. However, in those projects, other devs made too many calls to database to get a single record of MyObject and that's what I am trying to avoid. And yes, I read about DataTemplate but the code of MyCustomControl is too complex to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this fragment:

```
MyItem="{Binding MyObjectList/}"
```

In the following way:

```
MyItem="{Binding}"
```

In order to bind `MyItem` property to the current item in `MyObjectList`. I assume that `MyItem` is a dependency property.

Comment: If MyItem="{Binding}" does not help MyItem="{Binding .}" OR MyItem="{Binding Path=.}"is an equivalent syntanx for the same.

Comment: I already tried that before and got the following error message in Output window: System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'ProjectX.MyCustomControl' and 'ProjectY.MyObject'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MyCustomControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyCustomControl' (Name=''); target property is 'MyObject' (type 'MyObject')

Comment: Thank you Michal. It turns out there are some lines of code in MyCustomControl that prevent Binding working properly.